# ExecuteStoreQuery for custom columns

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to run custom query and I am using Entity framework, I tried this

```
string query = @"SELECT dm.DistrictName,sm.SchoolName,u.UserId,u.FirstName,u.LastName, sa.StudentId, sa.ReadingLevel
                 FROM  studentassessment sa
                 INNER JOIN assessmentmaster am ON sa.AssessmentId = am.AssessmentId
                 INNER JOIN studentclass sc ON sa.StudentId = sc.StudentId
                 INNER JOIN USER u ON sc.TeacherId = u.UserId
                 INNER JOIN schoolmaster sm ON u.SchoolCode = sm.SchoolCode
                 INNER JOIN  districtmaster dm ON sm.DistrictId = dm.DistrictId
                 WHERE u.RoleId = 5 && sa.GradeId = " + objParam.Grade + " && sa.AssessmentPeriodId = " + x.AssessmentPeriodId + " && dm.DistrictId = " + districtCode + " && am.DRAType = '" + objParam.LanguageType + "' && am.AssessmentTypeId = 1";



var dt = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<List<object>>(query).FirstOrDefault();
```

But didn't get succeed.

Is there any way to get results from `ExecuteStoreQuery` in the structure not mapped to any object type?

Answer (score 4):

No. EF's `ExecuteStoreQuery` requires data type (class) with properties with same names as columns in yours query result set. If you want to execute query without creating a special type for its result set you have to use ADO.NET and `SqlDataReader` directly.