# How to select varying amount of columns with ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm dynamically building a select query with a varying number of columns.

```
select
  a as col0,
  b as col1,
  ...,
  c as coln
...
```

The query is supposed to retrieve a matrix of integers.

When executing the query with `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`, I get the right amount of lines but each line seems to be empty.

Here is my code:

```
var lines = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<List<int>>(queryString).AsEnumerable()
```

How could I make it work?

---

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586938/1160770) that I should be using ADO.NET for this kind of things.

Comment: Your query is attempting to select multiple columns, while you're indicating that the result set will be a single column with multiple records (list of int).

This is untested, but consider returning dynamic (context.ExecuteStoreQuery<List<dynamic>>(...)).  This should return a list of readonly anonymous objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Entity Framework 6 does not have a lot of flexibility in the internal mapping code, so it is not able to map the SQL result to your `List<int>` or to any other collection of primitive types.

To understand why it is not able to do it, you need to know that internally EF6 uses a `DbDataReader` to read the SQL results, then it builds a `ColumnMap` from the expected generic result type (in your case the type is a generic List), and it performs a dynamic translation of the SQL results to a result object using the ColumnMap to know what column to map to what property of the object.

Per my explanation above, EF6 ExecuteStoreQuery method is trying to map your columns ("a", "b"..etc.) to the List object properties, and since **there are no properties on the List class that match your SQL result column names it is not able to map it**.

These limitations make ADO.NET one of the simplest option for dynamic columns. You can use a `DbDataReader` like in the following code:

```
var arr = new List<int>();

using (var md = new Context())
{
    var conn = md.Database.Connection;

    conn.Open();
    using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Col1,Col2 from Entities";

        using (var reader = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    arr.Add(reader.GetInt32(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```